# Sqlite reading/writing issue using Qt framework

Tags: qt, sqlite, qml, qtquick2

I have the following simple sqlite db code, written in Qt (`windowid` refers to the root element's `id`):

```
Rectangle{
    id:enterYourName
    anchors.centerIn: nameContianer
    color: "white"
    width:0.395*windowid.width
    height:0.227*windowid.height


    function getDatabase() {
        return LocalStorage.openDatabaseSync("HomeScreen", "1.0", "StorageDatabase", 100000);
    }


    function typetable() {
        var db = getDatabase();
        db.transaction(function(tx) {
            tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mycircletype (mytypee REAL)');
        });
    }


    function setType(yvalue) {
        var db = getDatabase();   
        db.transaction(function(tx) {
            tx.executeSql('INSERT OR REPLACE INTO mycircletype VALUES (?);', [yvalue]);

        }
        );
    }


    function getType() {
        var db = getDatabase();
        var res="";
        db.transaction(function(tx) {
            var rs = tx.executeSql('SELECT mytypee FROM mycircletype');         
            if (rs.rows.length > 0) {
                res = rs.rows.item(0).mytypee;
            } else {
                res = 0.506*windowid.height;
            }
        })     
        return res;
    }


    Component.onCompleted: {
        enterYourName.typetable()
    }
}
```

I also have an image, whose `y` value I would like to save, and three `Rectangle`s. When any of these `Rectangle`s is clicked the `y` value of the image changes to a specific value. I want to save that value and the next time my application starts I want that value to be the starting `y` value of my image. Here is my code:

```
// here is the image
Image{
    id:tick1
    source: "../../pics/tick.png"
    width:0.0395*windowid.width
    height:0.041*windowid.height
    x: 0.4474*windowid.width 
    y:  enterYourName.getType() //here the issue appears
    visible: false
}


// here are the 3 rectangles
Rectangle{
    id: op2op1
    x:windowid.width+10
    y:0.324*windowid.height
    width:0.170*windowid.width
    height:0.130*windowid.height

    MouseArea{
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            enterYourName.setType(0.370*windowid.height)
            tick1.y = 0.370*windowid.height
            tick1.visible = true
        }
    }
}


Rectangle{
    id: op2op2
    x:0.350*windowid.width
    y:0.364*windowid.height
    width:0.170*windowid.width
    height:0.130*windowid.height

    MouseArea{
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            enterYourName.setType(0.231*windowid.height)
            tick1.y = 0.231*windowid.height
            tick1.visible = true                         
        }
    }  
}


Rectangle{
    id: op2op3
    x:0.350*windowid.width
    y:0.364*windowid.height
    width:0.170*windowid.width
    height:0.130*windowid.height


    MouseArea{
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            enterYourName.setType(0.506*windowid.height)
            tick1.y = 0.506*windowid.height
            tick1.visible = true                      
        }
    } 
}
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting an error saying `Unable to assign null to double` pointing to the `y` value of the image:
    y: enterYourName.getType()
How can I fix this so that the `y` value of the image is saved and retrieved without any issues?

Comment: I would check if the `INSERT` actually inserts doubles into the database. Run `SELECT` after the insertion and display it in the log.